# 2014A AMC solution question

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

From:

[AMC 10 Q25 Solution](https://beyondmathsolutions.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/2014-amc-10a-problem-25/)

I get everything besides the last part. How in the world does he get:

$$3k + 2(867 - k) = 2013$$

I don't understand how he got this? What does this mean? Literally translated:

$$\text{3 times number of times we have 3 powers of 2 in between consecutive 5-powers}$$

$$\text{*Plus* 2 times the number of times we don't have 3 powers of 2 in between consecutive 5-powers. }$$

$$\text{Equals} \space 2013$$

How though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2013$ powers of $2$ considered. In the $k$ highlighted rows, there are $3$ powers each and in the other, there are $2$, thus the list contains $2013 = 3k + 2(867-k)$ powers of two.

Comment: Damn. That's all I got.

Comment: @Amad27 Huh? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I meant it's a great answer, simple, clear concise. This was in the interval, $(2^{2013}, 5^{867})$ right? What about in $(5^{867}, 2^{2014})$

Comment: @Amad27 It was actually the interval $(1, 2^{2013})$. For the $2014$ case you need to check if $2^{2016} < 5^{868}$. If that's the case, you get one more triple for the extended interval and if not, the solution is the same as for $(1,2^{2013})$.

Comment: Then what about $(2^{2013}, 5^{867})$?

Comment: The question is about that specific interval?

Comment: @Amad27 No, it's not. I think you misread the first sentence of the question. It asks for the number of integer solutions $(m,n)$ to $$5^n < 2^m < 2^{m+2} < 5^{n+1}$$ where $m \le 2012$, i.e. the powers of two ranging from $1 = 2^0$ to $2^{2014}$. From the first statement we can see that $2^{2013}<5^{867}<2^{2014}$ so $m = 2012$ can never be a solution.

Comment: It really is:

$$5^n < 2^m < 2^{m+1} < 2^{m+2} < 5^{n+1}$$

I don't understand why $m=2012$ doesnt work?

$$5^n < 2^{2012} < 2^{2013} < 2^{2014} < 5^{n+1}$$

Comment: Because there is a power of $5$ between $2^{2013}$ and $2^{2014}$. Also note that $2^m < 2^{m+1} < 2^{m+2}$ trivially so you can leave out the middle power.

Comment: If there is a power of $5$ between $2^{2013}$ and $2^{2014}$ how does that affect this?

Comment: @Amad27 Because the sandwiching powers $5^n$ and $5^{n+1}$ must be consecutive powers.

Comment: I really dont get what you are saying. Can you show me, which $n$ you are talking about?

Comment: $$5^{866}<2^{2013}<5^{867}<2^{2014}<5^{868}$$
This is the last thing I can try to help you understand it, since I don't know where you are stuck and it's getting really long for a comment exchange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21649/discussion-between-amad27-and-alexr).